# How to write the cmd in python file. curl -s url | grep 'Gitea (Git with a cup of tea)'

Tags: python

```
enter code here
```

curl -s url | grep 'Gitea (Git with a cup of tea)'

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

import subprocess

bash_com = 'curl -s url | grep Gitea (Git with a cup of tea)'
subprocess.Popen(bash_com)
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', bash_com])`